# How should I change the default highlight colour to the colour I want?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, evince

I can highlight text with evince, but if I want a different colour than the default one (yellow), I have to change each highlighted phrase separately. How can I change the default highlight colour to the colour I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there is no way to change the default color yellow to other according to this link https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotation-properties.html.en

```
Customize annotations

    In the Annotation Properties window, you can change the author, color, style and icon of your note.

    The annotation properties will be applied to the note for which you made the changes only. Each note can have a different set of properties.

Can I permanently change the default annotation properties?

The default annotation properties (author, colour, style and icon) can only be changed on a particular note as stated above. So if you want all icons for your notes to be red instead of yellow, you will have to change the default from yellow to red individually on each note. There is no way to save different default settings for annotation properties, at this time.
```

Comment: Do you have an idea as to why such a simple option has not been added to such a popular tool?

Comment: depending on more requests to the developers they will impliment in future versions..

Comment: For reference: here's the related issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1126